# How to print all lines ending with a particular string after stripping it?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I want to print all lines that has this string at its very end - `/Season $N`
. Here $N is any number that can either start from 0 or 01. Lastly Before printing such lines , i want to strip `/Season $N` from its end and remove duplicates if any ( can just use sort -u )

cat file.txt

```
SomeDir/path3/File.ext
SomeDir/Path/Season 5
SomeDir/path/Season 6
SomeDir/path/path/Season 10
SomeDir/path2/Season 19
Some Random String
SomeDir/path/path/Season 19
SomeDir/test/Season 56
```

Expected output

```
SomeDir/Path
SomeDir/path/path
SomeDir/path2
SomeDir/test
```

Comment: What have you tried? It is very difficult to help you with your code unless you [include it in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67981433/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you want

```
cat file.txt | awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '/Season/{NF--;print}' | sort -uf
```

(edit) but this is better:

```
awk -F/ -vOFS=/ '$NF ~ /Season [0-9]+/{NF--;print}' < file.txt | sort -fu
```

Comment: UUOC, + gawk-only variable assignment + undefined behavior on NF decrement + partial matching across the whole line instead of full matching on the last field. YMMV...